# Pass enum type as parameter

Tags: java, enums

### I want to create a method, that:

- Takes the **type of an enum** and a **String** as arguments

  - The String is the name of one specific enum instance
- Returns the enum instance that fits that name.

### What I have tried:

In class `TestUtil.java`:

```java
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E mapToEnum(Enum<E> mappingEnum, String data) {

    return mappingEnum.valueOf(E, data); // Not working, needs Class of Enum and String value
}
```

The enum:

```java
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1("A"),
    TEST2("B");

    private String value;

    private TestEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

How it should work (For example in main method):

```java
TestEnum x = TestUtil.mapToEnum(TestEnum.class, "TEST1"); // TEST1 is the name of the first enum instance
```

The problem is, that I can't figure out what I need to pass into the `mapToEnum` method, so that I can get the `valueOf` from that Enum.

Comment: what is `entry`?

Comment: what is entry.getKey()?

Comment: Why do you expect `mapToEnum` to work for every enum? What if it has no value? Also, the values in the enum are private, so how are you getting them?

Comment: @michalk My mistake - i minified a example to narrow down the problem. It should mean `data`.

Comment: @Michael every Enum I have worked with, has a valueOf method, which returns a Enum Instance, if the string provided matches.

Comment: and the `data` parameter should represent the enum *name* (`TEST1` for ex) or the enum property `value`?

Comment: @michalk If I understand the JavaDoc of `valueOf` correctly, it would be the name.

Comment: @MauriceNino Since the question is closed and I was just writing an answer - here's fix for your code. Use this method: static <T extends Enum<T>> T mapToEnum(Class<T> mappingEnum, String data) {
        return Enum.valueOf(mappingEnum, data);
    }

Comment: @Fenio Thank you a lot. I would really like to accept your answer, but unfortunately some people here like to abuse their power, by writing their (wrong) answers and then closing a question without good reasoning.

Comment: Minor suggestion to make your question a bit more clear: is `data` supposed to hold a value from a certain enum entry (like `"test1"`) or the actual name of the enum entry (like `"TEST1"`)? You've changed that in your question so it is a bit unclear to me. You could either change the values to different things like just "A" and "B" or remove them from the example so they don't distract.

Comment: @Fenio Reopened.  Technically the duplicate did have one answer which mentioned the static Enum.valueOf method, but it was kind of buried in a sea of answers, and it was contentious due to its swallowing of exceptions.

Comment: You can now accept my answer. The question has been reopened, thanks to @VGR

Comment: @Tom I edited the question for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you provided is acceptable:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E mapToEnum(Enum<E> mappingEnum, String data) {

    return mappingEnum.valueOf(E, data); // Not working, needs Class of Enum and String value
}
```

Then all you have to do is fix it.

Here's the code I tested:

```
static <T extends Enum<T>> T mapToEnum(Class<T> mappingEnum, String data) {
    return Enum.valueOf(mappingEnum, data);
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    TestEnum myEnum = mapToEnum(TestEnum.class, "TEST1");
    System.out.println(myEnum.value); //prints "A"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly suggest using [Apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library for boiler plate function like this ...

```java
TestEnum x = EnumUtils.getEnum(TestEnum.class, "TEST1");
```

... which is exactly the code @Fenio demonstrates but handles `null` or wrong input with a `null` instead of throwing an Exception.

If you didn't know about this then check out what the rest of the lang3 library holds. I view it as a de-facto standard, saving millions of devs from re-writing minor plumbing utilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate the enum class value and match with the parameter you have passed in the method, please check the below-mentioned code.

```
  enum TestEnum {
    TEST1("test1"),
    TEST2("test2");

   private String value;

   private TestEnum(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return value;
   }
   public static TestEnum mapToEnum(String data) {
       for (TestEnum userType : TestEnum.values()) {
           if (userType.getName().equals(data)) {
               return userType;
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also don't use `==` for string comparison